# Using Multiple Front End Package Managers Simultaneously (Bower, NuGet)

Tags: nuget, bower

The (unofficial) convention for writing NuGet packages for front-end libraries seems to be to strip out the JavaScript files and put them in the Scripts folder, and strip out the CSS files and put them in the Content folder. Rarely are these files put in subfolders, so you end up with a huge number of files littering the Scripts and Content folders.

The only way to separate your own code is to put that in a subfolder, or a different folder altogether (see the SPA templates Durandal and HotTowel where an "App" folder is added).

I personally like the "unopinionated" solution that Twitter Bower provides. Put all front-end packages in a root folder called "Components" and **do not mess** with the original structure of the package.

I am wondering about giving up on NuGet for front-end libraries and using Bower instead and just wonder if anyone has any experience of combining the two? Alternatively, is there a way to install GitHub repos directly using NuGet without creating a NuGet package?

Comment: Perhaps ask this on Programmers.SE? This question won't have a clear-cut correct answer.

Comment: I am surprised this question was closed. It really isn't that narrow a situation, in my opinion. There are two approaches to SPAs coalescing at the moment, the MS / Nuget / Durandal / WebAPI way or the Non-MS / Bower / Grunt / Node.js / AngularJS way.
This question is about the how you can mix the packaging component of one in the other. I think it is highly relevant to where things are in the community just now. An answer would surely have helped this future visitor.

Comment: You want answers?? You mean you didnt want to be downvoted in a jealous rage??? I agree, SO has gotten completely lame the past two years, for this very reason.

Comment: Nevermind what you do, but don't use different package managers together in one directory tree. This mess up the dependencys and clutter the Local-Package-Database if they use one. The first Package-Manager knows nothing about the second one and vice versa.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We use NuGet and Bower both and it has worked well for us so far. We are slowly moving the front-end libraries to Bower. You will have to create a Nuget package to use it from Nuget to install.

Comment: This is exactly what I decided to do and it works perfectly. Keep NuGet for server stuff and Bower for frontend.

Comment: So you are recommending creating a nuget package for bower (like others have done: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Bower/ )...rather than installing bower via npm.  Pros and Cons?